# Old leaves of Chinese Elm bonsai have gone brown at the edge and yellow at the center and then falling off

Tags: plant-health, watering, tree-care, bonsai

I have a 7 year old Chinese Elm bonsai. So far it has been growing new shoots without any problems. As of last week I noticed most of the leaves of the old shoots have started going yellow at the center and brown at the tip. After a while they become crispy and fall of the tree. It only seems to affect old shoots, as far as I can tell all the new shoots look normal to me. I’ve attached a picture for reference.

[image: single leaf]
[image: fallen leaves]

I normally wait until the soil looks dry (it changes color) before giving it a thorough watering.

Is this natural? Or could this be caused by overwatering? Under watering? Over fertilizing? What should I do?

I’ve also noticed a thin layer of white crust forming on top of the soil.

Comment: For me it is fertilizing or pH. Note that some component in fertilizers inhibits other components. Could you write more about what fertilizer and how often you do it?

Comment: I am using Pokon Bonsai plantfood. Mixing 2.5ml into a 500ml bottle and watering with the bottle once every week or so.

Comment: Where is the tree kept? Inside / outside?

Comment: @AvieRose It's kept inside.